# Secure websockets on hardware device

Tags: javascript, c#, ssl, websocket

I have a hardware device that is communicating over websockets with the Browser. The problem is that I want a secure connection, unfortunately browsers don't connect to self signed certificate. 
the problem is that every hardware device can have another IP, and certificates are limited on domains.
I cannot buy a certificate for each Hardware..  So what can I do?

Comment: How do other companies do with hardware devices where there has to be a secure connection? Do they have certificates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that I want a secure connection, unfortunately browsers don't connect to self signed certificate.

Certificates are used to securely identify the peer. Proper identification is necessary to make sure no man-in-the-middle attacks are possible. Thus it makes no sense to share the same certificate within 100's of different machines and you would have problems to keep the same private key secure anyway.

The alternative are self-signed certificates. But browsers don't connect without warning in this case, because if they would man-in-the-middle attacks would be trivial. This means that the user must explicitly acknowledge this certificate as  trusted and you have to educate the user how this must be done with the various browsers.

If browsers and devices are all under one control (like within a company-wide roll out) you might instead use your own PKI structure where all certificates are  issued by your own CA and this CA is trusted by all your browsers.

> the problem is that every hardware device can have another IP, and certificates are limited on domains.

No, certificates can be generated to identify IP addresses too. You will usually not get these certificates by a public CA, but a private CA can issue such certificates and self-signed certificates work too. Of course, using IP address instead of a name makes only sense if the IP will be constant for a very long time.

Comment: Can we create a pfx certificate file for using any IP. I have multiple IP addresses but I need to create one pfx and distribute it to all. So by doing that browser will not ask for acceptance when I type "https : //ipaddress" in all these machines?

Comment: 1.The problem is that browsers won't give you a chance to accept the self signed certificate if you are communicating with websockets. For https it is different. 2. The device IP-Address must be editable for the customer, if he wants the device in his network and it should have the address 192.168.55.123 than he should have the possibility to do this, this a the normal method. So wht is with this point. How can you create a certificate for this device if the ip address is always another and can change..

Comment: @OrkunBekar:  It is a bad idea to use the same certificate on all devices, because then the identification part does not really work and you have to use the same private key everywhere. But it would be possible to do this  if there are not too much devices, because you can put multiple IP addresses into the certificate.

Comment: @Franki1986: yes, you would need to first import the certificate as trusted, either manually or by visiting the site with https and creating an exception for the certificate. After then it should work with wss:// too, because wss:// is just a ws:// connection inside a https connection.

Comment: The thing with accepting the certificate over a https request is a good workaround! Thanks! But can I show an error from the client (browser) that a certificate is not valid? I mean the user doesn't really know what's the problem if only the connection cannot be made. So because it is a browser thing, how to get to know if the certificate will not be accepted by the browser (in javascript)?

Comment: @Franki1986: I don't know if I fully understand what you want, but from the server side you know if the user accepted the certificate, because then the SSL connection is successful. And on the client side you might first load a page without https which explains everything and with some javascript you can try to replace this page with another served by https. If this works the user has accepted the certificate and does not need the explanation any longer.